# Is the form domain of a self adjoint operator closed?

Tags: real-analysis, spectral-theory, self-adjoint-operators

If $\mu$ is a positive, finite measure on $\Bbb R$, define $Q=\{f\in L^2(\Bbb R,\mu): \int_{\Bbb R} |x| |f|^2\text d\mu<\infty\}$ and $q(f,g)=\int_{\Bbb R} x\bar f g\text d \mu$. Suppose there exists $M\ge 0$ s.t. $q(f,f)\ge -M||f||_{L^2}$ and let 
$$||f||_+^2=q(f,f)+(M+1)||f||_{L^2}^2$$
Is it true that $Q$ is complete under $||\cdot||_+$?

Since $||f||_+\ge ||f||_{L^2}$ and $L^2$ is complete, any Cauchy $f_n\in Q$ converges in the $L^2$ norm to some $f\in L^2$. It remains to show that $f\in Q$ and $q(f_n-f,f_n-f)\to 0$. In order to show that $\int |x||f|^2<\infty$ I thought about using Fatou's lemma but I have not managed to prove that $\liminf \int |x||f_n|^2<\infty$. The hint in the book says to use the dominated convergence theorem but I have no idea which dominating function to pick. Maybe the fact that $\mu(\Bbb R)<\infty$ and Egorov's theorem can help, but I have not been able to connect the dots, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: As $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Vert \cdot \Vert_+$, you get that $(\Vert f_n\Vert_+)$ is bounded and hence $(q(f_n, f_n))$ is bounded. Then you can apply Fatou to obtain $f\in Q$.

Comment: I guess you are missing an absolute value in the definition of $q$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I was hoping the missing absolute value was a typo in the book, but if $q(f,g)=\int |x|\bar f g\text d \mu$ then $q(f,f)\ge 0$, making the assumption that $q(f,f)\ge -M||f||^2$ redundant. I figure that the definition of $q$ has no typos. The book is Simon and Reed, Methods of Modern mathematical Physics, vol 1, chapter 8 in case my edition has an error.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven also, we may assume that $x\in L^p(\Bbb R,\mu)$ for all $1\le p<\infty$ if that helps.

Comment: I managed to produce something. However, it looks pretty messy. Probably it would work out nicer if I could implement your assumption on the moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My idea is to split the problem into two parts. We separate the positive and the negative real halfaxis so that we can control the stupid sign hidden in $q$.

Introduce the short notation $g_-= 1_{(-\infty, 0]}$ and $g_+= 1_{[0, \infty)}$ and $\nu(dx)= \vert x \vert \mu(dx)$, $\nu_-(dx)=  \vert x \vert \cdot 1_{(-\infty, 0]}(x) \mu(dx)$, $\nu_+(dx)=  \vert x \vert \cdot 1_{[0,\infty)}(x) \mu(dx)$ and $\mu_+(dx)=  1_{[0, \infty)}(x) \mu(dx)$.

We have 
$$ \Vert g \Vert_+^2 = \Vert g_+ \Vert_+^2 + \Vert g_- \Vert_+^2. $$
This reduces the problem to show convergence on the positive and on the negative reals.

**On the negative reals:**
We have
$$ \Vert g_- \Vert_{L^2(\mu)}^2 \leq \Vert g_- \Vert_+^2 = - \Vert g_- \Vert_{L^2(\nu)}^2 + (M+1) \Vert g_-\Vert_{L^2(\mu)} \leq (M+1) \Vert g_- \Vert_{L^2(\mu)} $$
Hence, if $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Vert \cdot \Vert_+$, then $((f_n)_-)$ is a Cauchy in $L^2(\mu)$ and (as $L^2(\mu)$ is complete) we get that it converges to some $f_-$. Thus, 
$$\Vert f_-- (f_n)_-\Vert_+^2 \leq \Vert f_- - (f_n)_- \Vert_{L^2(\mu)}^2 \rightarrow 0.$$ Hence,
$$ \Vert f_- - (f_n)_- \Vert_+^2 \rightarrow 0. $$

**On the positive reals:** We have
$$ \Vert g_+ \Vert_+^2 = \Vert g_+ \Vert_{L^2(\nu)}^2 + (M+1) \Vert g_+ \Vert_{L^2(\mu)}^2. $$
Hence, if $(f_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Vert \cdot \Vert_+$, then $((f_n)_+)$ is a Cauchy sequence in both $L^2(\mu)$ and $L^2(\nu)$. As both of them are complete, there exists limiting functions $f_+$ and $\tilde{f}_+$.

Recall that $L^2$ convergence implies pointwise convergence almost everywhere along a subsequence. Hence, we can pick a common subsequence which we call - by abuse of notation - again $((f_n)_+)$. This means $((f_n)_+)$ converges pointwise a.e. for both $\mu$ and $\nu$. However, as $(f_n)_+$ are supported on $[0,\infty)$, we get that $((f_n)_+)$ converges pointwise a.e. also in $\mu_+$ and $\nu_+$. But they have same zero sets ($\mu_+ \ll \nu_+ \ll \mu_+$) and thus, we get $f_+ = \tilde{f}_+$ both $\nu_+$ and $\mu_+$ a.e. Again as $f_+, \tilde{f}_+$ are supported in $[0,\infty)$ this means $f_+ = \tilde{f}_+$ $\mu$-a.e. and $\nu$-a.e.

Hence, we get that
$$ \Vert f_+ - (f_n)_+ \Vert_+^2 = \Vert f_+ - (f_n)_+\Vert_{L^2(\nu)}^2 + (M+1)\Vert f_+ - (f_n)_+\Vert_{L^2(\mu)}^2
= \Vert \tilde{f}_+ - (f_n)_+\Vert_{L^2(\nu)}^2 + (M+1)\Vert f_+ - (f_n)_+\Vert_{L^2(\mu)}^2 \rightarrow 0. $$

**On the whole real axis:**

Now we define $f:= f_- + f_+$, then we get
$$ \Vert f - f_n \Vert_+^2 = \Vert f_- - (f_n)_-\Vert_+^2 + \Vert f_+ - (f_n)_+ \Vert_+^2 \rightarrow 0. $$